# What web browsers are supported by meteor web framework?

Tags: meteor

Specifically which versions of Internet Explorer browser are supported?

Answer (score 10):

The core Meteor packages support IE6 and above.  I fixed the out-of-date message in `unsupported.html`.

Comment: but what about websocket stuff, I mean Meteor does live update, doesn't it? Fallback or polyfill?

Comment: Meteor uses Socket.IO, which uses a few fallback methods, like polling. It even supports IE5.5. See http://socket.io/#browser-support

Comment: Where can one find this `unsupported.html`?

Comment: @konrad Meteor uses sockjs not socket.io

Answer (score 3):

According to Meteorpedia, here are the supported browsers and their version :

> - Android stock browser (Webkit based)
> - Chrome
> - Firefox 7+
> - iOS browser
> - IE8+
> - Safari 4+
> - Desktop Opera
> - Mobile Opera

More info at : [Meteorpedia - Supported Browsers](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Supported_Browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like anything above IE 5 if you view the source on browser support.
There is supposed to be a browser support page but it looks disabled.

I'm working towards a static browser fix so search engines and older browsers get some form of page.