# Meteor requirements (client and server)

Tags: browser, meteor, compatibility, legacy, requirements

I'm evaluating using Meteor to develop in legacy systems.

What are Meteor app requirements to be executed in a browser?
(i.e. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Webkit, Opera, versions?)

And, the same question applied to run it as an app server in an old machine with old O.S.
(i.e. Windows XP, Ubuntu 9.04, Fedora 8, and their subcomponents/requirements)

Thanks!

Comment: your first question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127211/what-web-browsers-are-supported-by-meteor-web-framework and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001866/meteor-compatibility
give the search a try!

Comment: Thanks! I searched by minimum requirements and other terms, but it didn't returned these results you're pointing to. Anyway, I hope it will serve as reference for anyone searching for "requirements". I have edited the tags to reflect these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**client:**

yes, most modern browsers will support and it degrades well (socksjs if no websockets)...  But there are a lot of client side dependencies you will probably use, eg: jquery, amplify, etc...

there is an extra package for IE redirect if not "nice" enough:
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/redirect-ie-7-lower

**server:**

not really on windows... they have makeshift support for it now.
I've had no issue on ubuntu (most recent 2 versions) nor osx (1 version old).  Meteror's dependencies are mostly abstracted by NodeJS.