# Which headless browsers are supported by Meteor?

Tags: meteor

We know [which desktop browsers are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127211/what-web-browsers-are-supported-by-meteor-web-framework) by Meteor, but which headless browsers are officially supported?

Answer (score 1):

I have never read any statement regarding headless browser support for Meteor, but from my own experience using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), I am pretty sure it would be a safe bet.

Comment: So far, I've only tried [Zombie.js](zombie.labnotes.org) for my integration tests. Things appear to function correctly in Zombie, until you attempt to visit the same page (i.e. index) in a second test. At that point, Zombie complains about templates being rerendered:

> Zombie: There are multiple templates named '_loginButtons'. Each template needs a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Phantomjs and do not see any problems using it with Meteorjs.

As far as support for it check out this post from meteor's blog :
http://meteor.com/blog/2012/08/08/search-engine-optimization

Looks like it does...

Comment: Justin, I appreciate the reference to the post, though that just says that the spiderable package has a PhantomJS dependency. That being said, thanks for the extra confirmation that PhantomJS works as expected. I'm still looking for an official list of *all* headless browsers that are officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

I've used casperjs. It works well for single-browser testing. HOWEVER: watch out, casperjs/phantomjs can only simulate one browser at a time. If you want to test multiuser functionality using separate headless browsers, you will have to use something else (or perhaps run multiple casperjs in separate node.js instances).

Trying other options:

- zombie.js doesn't seem to work; it seems not smart enough to handle templates, though perhaps you could get it working with some fiddling.
- ghost.py also seems to fail on a simple meteor page load, though it's possible I'm just doing something wrong.
- I have yet to try spynner.py, envjs, or others.

Comment: For multiple users any browser that can separate local storage between sessions (or disable the meteor local storage) should work: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/yKS05CPZ-SM

Comment: zombie.js is able to read a website done with Meteor.js at least the one i did recently!